# Как в Modx Revo вывести всех пользователей определенной группы?

Tags: php, api, modx, revo, users

Есть ли возможность вывести всех пользователей из определенной группы?

Все пишу в сниппете, но могу и во внешнем файле с помощью api Modx

```
//Инициализируем запрос
$query = $modx->newQuery('modUser');
// выполняем запрос
$users = $modx->getCollection('modUser',$query);



// цикл по пользователям
foreach ($users as $user) {

...
}
```

Так получится вывести всех пользователей сайта, а как из определенной группы? Например, из группы **boys**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
$gName = 'boys';
$group = $modx->getObject('modUserGroup', array ('name' => $gName));
$users = $group->getMany('UserGroupMembers');
foreach($users as $user) {
    if ($user->get('active') {
        $userdata = $user->toArray();
        $profile = $user->getOne('Profile');
        $profileData = $profile->toArray();
        // тут любые дальнейшие манипуляции с пользователями и их данными
    }
}
```

Comment: только в **foreach** ничего не выводится почему-то. Однако если сделать **count($users)**, то показывает правильное кол-во юзеров в группе

Comment: Может массив надо разобрать как-то по-другому?